# convert string to corresponding street number

Tags: python, string, geocoding, street-address

I'm working with US addresses whose have an inconsistent format, E.G in the street number:

```
358 SEVENTH AVENUE MANHATTAN 10001
```

I need it to be as:

```
358 7th Ave, New York, NY 10001
```

Using a addresses parser like [usaddress](https://usaddress.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I can separate out the street name:

```
SEVENTH AVENUE
```

From this, I could handle the issue as:

```
numbers_mapping = {'seventh':'7th','eight':'8th'}

street_name = 'SEVENTH AVENUE'
street_name = street_name.lower()

for key in numbers_mapping:
    if key in street_name.split():
        street_name = street_name.replace(key,numbers_mapping[key])

print street_name
7th avenue
```

I have to problems with this approach:

1) First, I don't know how many streets numbers are valid and I don't want to create manually create a too large dictionary for a problem that seems to be common.

2) Handling strings is always tricky and I might be ignoring an important number of cases with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet by [ghewgill](https://github.com/ghewgill) which converts textual number notations to numeric ones.

The link to the script can be found [here](https://github.com/ghewgill/text2num/blob/master/text2num.py).

In the above code snippet, I was able to get the desired result by making the following modifications:

```
Small = {
'zeroth': 0,
'first': 1,
'second': 2,
'third': 3,
'fourth': 4,
'fifth': 5,
'sixth': 6,
'seventh': 7,
'eighth': 8,
'ninth': 9,
'tenth': 10,
'eleventh': 11,
'twelfth': 12,
'thirteenth': 13,
'fourteenth': 14,
'fifteenth': 15,
'sixteenth': 16,
'seventeenth': 17,
'eighteenth': 18,
'nineteenth': 19,
'twenty': 20,
'thirty': 30,
'forty': 40,
'fifty': 50,
'sixty': 60,
'seventy': 70,
'eighty': 80,
'ninety': 90
```

}

With the main function as :

```
num = texttonum("string_evquivalent")
if num == 1:
    print str(num) + 'st'
elif num == 2:
    print str(num) + 'nd'
else:
    print str(num) + 'th'
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

import re

numbers_mapping = {'seventh':'7th','eight':'8th'}

street_name = 'SEVENTH AVENUE'

street_name = street_name.lower()

for key in numbers_mapping:

```
      if re.search(key,street_name.split(" ")[0],re.I):

            street_name = street_name.replace(key,numbers_mapping[key])
```

print street_name

7th avenue

Comment: Please try this, it may help